# Most efficient tool to store frequent temperature samples

Tags: database, temperature

I'm working on a system that will need to store lots of temperature data. I could potentially store 5 samples per second or more.

I've done this in the past with a relatively simple mysql database and performance became unbearable. Inserts were not too bad, but had a noticeable load. Queries, however, could take minutes.

At that time, I had something like 50 gb of data, which is ridiculous. I can think of many ways to compress or discard data without losing critical information, but that's a completely different problem.

I'd like to pick a tool/database that is optimized for this kind of data, preferably cross platform (at a minimum, linux/c++).

RRD (Round Robin Database) seems built for this kind of thing, but it seems designed more for processing data than for storing it.

What other tools are available?

Edit: more info...

This will be running on an embedded system (a Raspberry Pi) so an ideal tool has low computing overhead, low memory footprint, and few library dependencies.

The storage may not necessarily be on the same device.

I suppose growth could reach as much as 500k samples per hour in a contrived, extreme case. More likely it will be about 20k samples per hour.

Internet access should not be presumed.

Comment: You may want to look into NoSQL or partitioning. I don't see why MySQL wouldn't be able to handle this amount of data.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're looking for a time series DB.

I know of two candidates:

- http://tempo-db.com/
- http://opentsdb.net/

If you could be a bit more specific about your requirements (req/s, daily data growth, API type, self-hosted or a fully managed solution, etc), I'd be able to go into more details or recommend other solutions.

Good luck.

Comment: thanks, "time series" is exactly what I'm after. these suggestions look good, but the first is very expensive and the second carries a bit of bloat.